# Cocos2D: In the .7.2 version how do I write simple text?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Due to certain circumstances (not having admin's administatrion on a computer that isn't mine) I can't use the latest version of cocos2D.

How am I able to write simple text on that version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would really try and get the latest version as you could imagine 7.2 is long non supported I would think.

However it should be as simple as:

```
        //Make your text.
        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Your text!" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:24];
        //Choose a position on the screen.
        label.position = ccp(240, 160);
        //Add it to the scene.
        [self addChild:label];
```